# HQL eqvivalent query for this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

My entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SMSSalesData")
public class SMSSalesDataEntity implements Serializable{
@Id @GenericGenerator(name = "native_generator", strategy = "native")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "native_generator")
private Integer ID;

@Column(name="CMSCode", length=50)
private String cmsCode;

@Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "MSQty", precision = 20)
private Double msQty;

@Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "HSDQty", precision = 20)
private Double hsdQty;

@Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "LubesQty", precision = 20)
private Double lubesQty;

@Column(name = "MobileNo", length = 20)
private String mobileNo;

@Column(name = "MsgDatetime")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date msgDatetime;

@Column(name = "CreatedDatetime", length = 20)
private Date createdDatetime;

@Column(name = "shortcode", length = 20)
private String shortcode;

@Column(name = "productcode", length = 20)
private String productcode;

@Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "MSStock", precision = 20)
private Double msStock;

@Digits(integer = 18, fraction = 2)
@Column(name = "HSDStock", precision = 20)
private Double hsdStock;
```

I want Hibernate query for this entity class to get sum of MSQty according month and year of msgDateTime group by month of msgDateTime.

```
SELECT  SUM(MSQty) as sum_ms_qty FROM SMSSalesData where MONTH(MsgDatetime)=10 and YEAR(MsgDatetime)=2014 GROUP BY MONTH(MsgDatetime) ;
```

Above is this SQL query for the Getting sum for this MSQty.

Can you pls provide me hibernate or criteria query for the same.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HQL:

```
SELECT sum(SMSSalesDataEntity.MSQty) as sum_ms_qty 
from SMSSalesDataEntity 
WHERE month(SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDatetime)= 10 and year(SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDatetime) = 2014 
GROUP BY month(SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDatetime)
```

HQL Docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

for **dateadd and datediff** custom functions needs to be added based on the database you are connecting to **[Date operations in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568914/date-operations-in-hql?rq=1)**

```
SELECT SUM(MSQty) + SUM(HSDQty) FROM [essar].[dbo].[SMSSalesData] WHERE [MsgDatetime] < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and [MsgDatetime] > DATEADD(Month, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, MsgDatetime), 0);
```

in HQL:

```
SELECT SUM(SMSSalesDataEntity.MSQty) + SUM(SMSSalesDataEntity.HSDQty) FROM SMSSalesDataEntity
WHERE SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDatetime < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDateTime >
DATEADD(MONTH, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SMSSalesDataEntity.msgDateTime), 0);
```

Comment: Thank u piratheep.. can u pls provide HQL for this too..              SELECT SUM(MSQty) + SUM(HSDQty)     
  FROM [essar].[dbo].[SMSSalesData] WHERE [MsgDatetime] < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and [MsgDatetime] > DATEADD(Month, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, MsgDatetime), 0);

Comment: for dateadd and datediff custom functions needs to be added based on the database you are connecting to Date operations in HQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568914/date-operations-in-hql?rq=1