# How to add date in mysql database from Hibernate/Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I use  spring boot, and I want to add 1 year to a specific column in mysql database

```
String queryRecherche = "UPDATE myTable t SET t.dateDebut = DATE_ADD(t.dateDebut, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) WHERE.id = 3 ";
Query query = em.createQuery(queryRecherche);;
query.executeUpdate();
```

But I get the folowing error :

```
org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:66 no viable alternative at input 'DATE_ADD(t.dateDebut,INTERVAL1'
```

Have you please any suggestions to do this.

Comment: `createQuery` is for JPQL, you want `createNativeQuery` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Hibernate 6 (I can tell by the error message), so the correct HQL syntax to use is:

```
UPDATE MyEntity t SET t.dateDebut = t.dateDebut + 1 year WHERE t.id = 3
```

You had three errors in your query:

1. You referred to the name of a table instead of the name of an *entity class* in the `UPDATE` clause.
2. You used the unportable MySQL `DATE_ADD` function instead of the portable HQL date/time arithmetic [described here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-Datetime-arithmetic).
3. The syntax of your `WHERE` clause was garbled.

Perhaps you meant for this to be a native SQL query, in which case you called the wrong method of `Session`. But there's no need to use native SQL for the above query. As you can see, HQL is perfectly capable of expressing that query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL directly, via createNativeQuery, or register a new function  as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568914/date-operations-in-hql) to call it from HQL

Comment: He doesn't need to register a function here because he's using H6 which has built-in support for date/time arithmetic.