# How to increment days for JPA without using interval?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make the moduleEndDate field 90 days in the future. If I run this in the database natively from Postgre, it doesn't return any error, but if I apply it to JPA I get an error.

> 2023-07-25 14:22:35.099 [main] ERROR o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker
>
> - line 1:103: unexpected token: INTERVAL antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: INTERVAL

The specific query is customized for JPA:

```
public interface ICourseDataRepository extends JpaRepository<CourseData, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT cd FROM course_data cd WHERE :activeDate between cd.module_start_date and cd.module_end_date + INTERVAL '90 DAY'")
    public List<CourseData> findActiveCourses(@Param("activeDate") LocalDateTime activeDate);

}
```

If I directly try to take the field and add it for the number of seconds in a day **cd.module_end_date + 90 * 86400** I can't either because the field is of the timestamp type... I can't think of any other way for JPA to accept it and be compatible with Postgre.

I update that I have tried to do it with native query in this way and it returns another error:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cd FROM course_data cd WHERE ?1 between cd.module_start_date and cd.module_end_date + INTERVAL '90 DAY'",
        nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findActiveCourses(@Param("activeDate") LocalDateTime activeDate);
```

And it returns the following error:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for
> JDBC type: 2002; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException:
> No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

Comment: Make it a native query. Otherwise you would need to [register a new function with HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568914/date-operations-in-hql). As a side note: https://www.coding-dude.com/wp/hibernate/hql-current-date/ this lists possible options for you

Comment: If I do a native query as you say, it stops for a while and I get the message: "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002",

Comment: To fix that is probably out of scope of this question. According to the 2nd link I posted, you could try in the HQL something like this: `WHERE :activeDate between cd.module_start_date and cd.module_end_date + 90` This requires `module_end_date` to be date without time though